# Basic Javascript name input validation

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

Hi I'm new to javascript and just wanted to do a basic else if name input validation. I keep running into the same issue. It directly goes to else. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Project</title>
</head>
<body>

   <label id =myLabel>Enter your friends name:</label><br>
   <input id="textField" type="text" placeholder="Enter name"><br>
   <button id="submitBtn" type="button">Submit</button><br>
   <p id="outputName"></p>

    
    

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
let username = document.getElementById("textField").value;
let submit = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
let output = document.getElementById("outputName");


submit.onclick = function(){
    if(username === "Rodney" || username === "rodney"){
        output.innerHTML = username + " access denied";
        
    }
        
    else if(username === "Alexander" || username === "alexander"){
        output.innerHTML = username + " access granted";
        
    }
    else{
        output.innerHTML = username + " not defined";
    }

}
```

I would like to output the name and access granted or denied in the paragraph tag with the id of outputName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've saved an empty username value from when the user didn't type anything yet

You have to get the value in `onclick`

```
let submit = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
let output = document.getElementById("outputName");


submit.onclick = function(){
    let username = document.getElementById("textField").value;
    if(username === "Rodney" || username === "rodney"){
        output.innerHTML = username + " access denied";
        
    }
        
    else if(username === "Alexander" || username === "alexander"){
        output.innerHTML = username + " access granted";
        
    }
    else{
        output.innerHTML = username + " not defined";
    }

}
```

or

```
let usernameField = document.getElementById("textField")
let submit = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
let output = document.getElementById("outputName");


submit.onclick = function(){
    const username = usernameField.value;
    if(username === "Rodney" || username === "rodney"){
        output.innerHTML = username + " access denied";
        
    }
        
    else if(username === "Alexander" || username === "alexander"){
        output.innerHTML = username + " access granted";
        
    }
    else{
        output.innerHTML = username + " not defined";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in 'submit' function, you are checking with empty value. So, once user clicks on button, you need to get updated value entered by user and then compare it in if-else block.